# How to stream "dialog" output to stdout?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, dialog

I am trying to automate a task on a file using Python pwntools.

However, no matter what I do I am unable to get the output.

Based on the behavior of the program (for example: that it takes up the entire terminal window, among other things) I believe that it is displayed using the `dialog` command.

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to capture the data.

Even if I try `script output.txt` and run either the file or, for example, `dialog --yesno "\nBla bla bla...\n\nDo you accept?" 10 30` the output just isn't captured.

I would also like to capture the data while the program is running, I do not want to close it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.stdout=open("test.txt","w")
print ("hello")
sys.stdout.close()
```

Now the hello will be written to the test.txt file. Make sure to close the stdout with a close, without it the content will not be save in the file

Comment: This does not answer the question described. All your code does is redirect the stdout to a file. I am trying to figure out how to get stdout working in the first place